# Code Highlighter Sunburst not selecting whole code when double clicking

Tags: javascript, html

I am using **Highlighter** to display my code inside my website [LINK](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styles/index.html) I had applied **Sunburst** theme My problem is when I double clicking on that code, the whole code should be selected But it is not happening.

[Video for demo](http://www.screenr.com/DSdH)